# How to add Composer autoload classmap at runtime

Tags: php, composer-php, runtime, autoload

Adding directories for Composer autoloading in this way (composer.json)

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "/var/www/lib",
        "/var/www/source"
    ]
}
```

but it is always annoying to run composer dumpautoload each time when creatinng new classes in my own project directories.

How can I add my dirs at runtime?

P.S. I know what is PSR-4. But when you have more then 100 classes and using hundreds of templates for HTML rendering - this is not solution. I will have to write a lot of "use foo\bar" in templates. That is abnormal.

Comment: Load classes PSR-4 style instead of classmap.

Comment: You should write [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) compatible project structures. That way you can use the [psr-4](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4) section in your composer.json.

Comment: @MattS, I know that. But in this case I will have to define tonns of "use" inside my hundreds html templates. That is the problem.

Comment: You could set up PSR-0 in the autoloader and keep everything in the root namespace.  No need to add `use` statements.  Or skip composer and write a custom autoloader.  A basic autoloader is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways to tell Composer how to find classes that are not recorded in the classmap, and that is PSR-0 and PSR-4. PSR-0 works for all types of classes, and PSR-4 only works for classes in namespaces.

One should generelly be able to structure the code into either PSR-0 or PSR-4, especially if it is new code being written - that's why classmap autoloading is only considered as a way to be able to deal with old legacy code that does not conform to PSR. Using classmap autoloading for new code is abnormal.